# Either a new blank page created or my paragraph moved in front of my table, after i use hyperef to create bookmarks automatically

Tags: tables, bookmarks

I want to create bookmarks automatically using the sentence `\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}`, but the paragraph i worte after my table will come in front of the table.
After i use the table environment trying to use the command like [!hbp], there will be a odd new blank page between the previous section and the section my table belongs to.

I want to know if there is a solution other than put a sentence between the header and my table, which i tried proved to be helpful.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass[UTF-8,openany]{ctexart}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newenvironment{enabstract}{
    \par\small
    \noindent\mbox{}\hfill{\bfseries \enabstractname}\hfill\mbox{}\par
    \vskip 2.5ex}{\par\vskip 2.5ex} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}  %大于等于geqslant，小于等于leqslant
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand{\li}{\uline{\hspace{0.5em}}}
\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\geometry{left=3.15cm, right=3.15cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.10cm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents 
\newpage
\subsection {delete P permutation}
\subsubsection{description}
123。
\subsubsection{result}
\par    
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth, natwidth=1194,natheight=774]{2.4.2.png}
        \end{center}
\subsubsection{analysis}
\par 

\begin{table*}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|L{4cm}|L{4cm}|L{4cm}|}
    \hline
    & 对照组 &实验组（删除P置换）\\ \hline
    massage x &1 &1\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|C{12cm}|}{第1轮}  \\ \hline
    E(R0)  &   2  &2\\   \hline
    E(R0)\^{} K1&2&2\\ \hline
    S(E(R0)\^{}K1) &6 &6\\ \hline
    P(S(E(R0)\^{}K1))&6& \\ \hline
    R1 &6&6\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{第2轮}  \\ \hline
    E(R1)  &   10 &9 \\   \hline
    E(R1)\^{} K2&10&9\\ \hline
    S(E(R1)\^{}K2) &14&10\\ \hline
    P(S(E(R1)\^{}K2))&14& \\ \hline
    R2 &15&9 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{第3轮}  \\ \hline
    E(R2)  &   22 &12 \\   \hline
    E(R2)\^{} K3&22&12\\ \hline
    S(E(R2)\^{}K3) &21&6\\ \hline
    P(S(E(R2)\^{}K3))&21& \\ \hline
    R3 &19 &6\\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{第4轮}  \\ \hline
    E(R3)  &   30&9 \\   \hline
    E(R3)\^{} K4&30&9\\ \hline
    S(E(R3)\^{}K4) &16&8\\ \hline
    P(S(E(R3)\^{}K4))&16& \\ \hline
    R4 &13&9 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{第5轮}  \\ \hline
    E(R4)  &   18 &13\\   \hline
    E(R4)\^{} K5&18&13\\ \hline
    S(E(R4)\^{}K5) &17&9\\ \hline
    P(S(E(R4)\^{}K5))&17& \\ \hline
    R5 &14&11 \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{第6轮}  \\ \hline
    E(R5)  &   18 &17 \\   \hline
    E(R5)\^{} K6&18&17\\ \hline
    S(E(R5)\^{}K6) &18&8\\ \hline
    P(S(E(R5)\^{}K6))&18& \\ \hline
    R6 &13 &9\\ \hline
    cipher y &33 &33\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\par 可以看到有无P置换对加密过程中制造雪崩效应的速度有一定影响作用，尽管前$6$轮变化比特的数目增加较慢，但事实上由于加密轮数充分长，观察最后几轮可以发现，$R_i$等数据的变化比特数目接近期望，最终密文变化的比特数目和对照组是一致的。
\subsection{summarize}
\begin{itemize}
\item 当一个比特变化的概率是$\frac{1}{2}$时，其熵是最大的。所以我们希望改变任意单个明文比特或密钥比特都会使密文的每一个比特以$\frac{1}{2}$的概率改变。标准DES算法使得明文输入的一个比特的变化引起密文输出的比特有$33$位变化，符合平均的发生变化的期望。
\item E扩散操作对于在加密过程中制造雪崩效应的速度和程度有一定的影响作用，但不是决定性作用。另外，扩散操作使得改变输入的一个比特后最终密文的变化数目更接近于期望。
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document will give you "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref."  upon compiling. This is cause by loading `hyperref` twice with different options. Please make sure, you only load packages once.

Comment: Thanks! I tailored my code to ask this question, so the package is included twice in accident. i found that things will be fine and all the problems have gone away after i make my tabular smaller as it is larger than the previous set of page now. Still, thanks a lot.

Comment: For tables that are too long to fit onto a single page, you might want to take a look at the `longtable` package.

Comment: I will try! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tailored my code to ask this question, so the package is included twice in accident, but it's not the main problem.

I found that things will be fine and all the problems have gone away after i make my tabular smaller as it is larger than the previous set of page now. The tabular is like overflow the page, so the odd blank page went out. Or if i put it in a float environment, the paragraphs and the section after the page will come in fron of the page as defined.

In short, it's not about a tabular can't be put right after a section head, it's simply because my tabular is so large that it overflowed.